# Configuring PHPMailer on Siteground shared hosting plan

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am stuck trying to make PHPMailer to work with my website hosted on Siteground.

I installed it by composer via PuTTY, everything looking fine so far:

[image: PuTTY console screenshot]

But when I try to test it, I can't get it to work properly.

Here is a sample of my testing code:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host       = '**HOST**';
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    $mail->Username   = '**MAILACCOUNT**';
    $mail->Password   = '**PASSWORD';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
    $mail->Port       = 465;

    $mail->setFrom('**MAILACCOUNT**', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('**TESTMAILRECIPIENT', 'test');

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

Which is a modified version of the template PHPMailer provides on their github.

All of my credentials are good (host, mail account, password). I tried with different ports (25, 587) and as per Siteground the good port for SMTP is **465**. But nothing work. The **try catch block** does not even catch any error, sometimes depending of what I try my webpage stays blank, or return a **HTMLERROR 500**.

I tried to reach out their technical support but they don't seem to have a clue about anything. They sent me the link to the [PHPMailer github](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), telling me to follow the tutorial.

There is absolutely no documentation about using this PHP library with their services. I have been searching for 2 days now. It seems they have changed their interface, as many - if not all - of their tutorials are for an older version of their cPanel.

Maybe it could have something to do with **SPF and DKIM protocols**? DKIM is active on my account, SPF I have absolutely no clue what to do with this.

Here is my generated SPF record, if ever you need to know:

`v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:**MYIP** include:_spf.mailspamprotection.com ~all`

I tried many online tutorials and adapted them to my needs with Siteground, with no success.

Is there anybody used to their system and could help me getting this to work?

I use a shared hosted plan, if it helps. They use Linux servers.

Thank you very much!

Comment: You’ve not done any of the things discussed in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide. Go there first, do what it says, post the results in your question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's your problem, but by my experience, Siteground and other hosts provider disable the PHPMailer by default for security reasons. You may check that if it's your case.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is looking for the same thing - for me what worked is the next:

1. prefixing the host with "ssl://"
2. in PHPMailer instance setting:

   $mail->SMTPSecure = false;

   $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;

Also the port I used was 465.

Very strange combination of settings, but at least it worked in my case.

Comment: Thanks so much, I would have never figured that out on my own. This combination of settings still works for SiteGround in 2022 

Comment: Still works in 2024, too. For me, all it took was the ssl:// prefix on host. However, I did at first also include the Secure and AutoTLS lines and it worked fine then, too.